# Unrecognised selector error for a UITableView in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app use `MMDrawerController`in order to implement a left drawer which handle a simple menu. A entry of this menu refers to a `UITabController` which I instantiate in this way.

```
mainWindowController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UITabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

Now, the first `UIViewController` used by the TabController has a table view which uses a custom `UIViewCell`. The class for the custom cell is this:

```
class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newsText: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

}

I checked that the outlets are properly connected with the correct storybook element. However, my app crash at this instruction,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCell
```

with the following error: `exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff4d362a6f0'`.

It seems like I have no set the proper identifier in my inspector; however, obviously, I have done it. The situation of my storyboard is this:

[image]

Do anyone have any suggestions which can explain this problem? I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you are using isEqualToString Method and instead of passing string to that method,UILabel is passing. Please check. Otherwise put that code, I'll check and let you know.

Comment: I deleted and recreated my `UILabel` from scratch and now it works properly! I was no using no isEqualToString method in my code. Could you me better explain what you mean for that I was passing a `UILabel` to that method please?

Comment: please add exception breakpoint in your project. it will stop where the bug exactly occurs and post the code here to get the better understanding on your doubt.

Comment: @GiovanniGrano As you can see in logs
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff4d362a6f0' It means somewhere isEqualToString method getting fired with UILabel whether it's in your code or any third party.